# Simple if statement?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I've got a simple if statement that involves 4 UIImageViews I want to detect when all 4 are nil to trigger something. It works just fine as it is but I am getting a warning that says "expression result unused".

```
if (shapeImage1, shapeImage2, shapeImage3, shapeImage4 == nil){   
    NSLog(@"Hello, friend.");    
}
```

Comment: I think it won't work the way you expect.

Comment: (This is a common problem in most languages -- there's no concise way to apply the same criterion to several values, nor is there a concise way to test a value between limits, such as (the bogus) `if (5 < a < 10)`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only checking if the `UIImageView` **shapeImage4** is nil. If you want to check if they are all nil, try:

```
if((shapeImage1 == nil) && (shapeImage2 == nil) && (shapeImage3 == nil) && (shapeImage4 == nil)){
    NSLog(@"Hello, friend.");
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what it was! Dang. Thank you @msgambel - I will accept your answer asap. There is a time limit here on SO.

Answer (score 4):

The comma operator discards the first result (meaning all but the last is actually tested) so you'll need to test every instance:

```
if (!shapeImage1 && !shapeImage2 && !shapeImage3 && !shapeImage4) {
    NSLog(@"Hello, friend.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a comma in C (or Objective-C), you’re making four different expressions. In this case, only one of those values is actually *used* in the `if` statement. What you want is to use the `||` (OR) operator, like this:

```
if (shapeImage1 == nil || shapeImage2 == nil || shapeImage3 == nil || shapeImage4 == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Hello, friend.");
}
```

You can optimize this further:

```
if (!shapeImage1 || !shapeImage2 || !shapeImage3 || !shapeImage4) {
    NSLog(@"Hello, friend.");
}
```

Comment: That doesn't test that every instance is `nil`.

Comment: You probably should be using `&&`, per the OP's description.

Answer (score 0):

i am no expert with objective C but why not do:

```
if (shapeImage1 == nil && shapeImage2 == nil && shapeImage3 == nil && shapeImage4 == nil)
{

    NSLog(@"Hello, friend.");

}
```